# Pipe decrypted password to command

Tags: password, ubuntu-mate, pipe

I would like to modify this so, my password is never visible.
The method would need to work standalone and in scripts.

```
echo fake | sudo -S thunar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question it's not clear what you mean by "never visible". Somewhere the password needs to be stored if you don't want to type it. But you can make it invisible for the command line.

Create a file with your password: `~/.userpass`

```bsh
userpass="fake"
```

Make it only visible to you:

```bsh
chmod 600 ~/.userpass
#or 400 to make it readonly
```

Then you can run commands like this:

```bsh
source ~/.userpass # once per session
echo "$userpass" | sudo -S thunar
```

---

Alternatively, you can edit your `sudoers` file to allow passwordless access via `sudo` to all or certain commands.

```
sudo visudo
```

and add the following line to the end of the file:

```
username ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

or

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/thunar
```

(Change username to your actual username)

Comment: So, will it need to run source ~/.userpass each time I log in?

Comment: You can add this to your .bashrc

Comment: I tried adding it, but it did not work. I put echo "$userpass" | sudo -S thunar into a script. It works from a terminal but not when I try to invoke it using thunar.

Answer (score 0):

[@RoVo](https://askubuntu.com/users/631600/rovo)'s [response](https://askubuntu.com/a/1067389/504066) already answered your question on how to pass a password to `sudo -S` but I'd like to focus on a pure `sudo` solution.

This has some advantages in my opinion:

1. You don't need to maintain a file with your cleartext password.
   In case you change your password, you would also need to change 
   the file `~/.userpass` accordingly.
2. User `root` can see your password in either your environment
   or by a simply issuing `cat ~fixit/.userpass`. Although `root` 
   won't need your password to do something on your behalf (as he
   can always do `su - fixit` or `sudo -u fixit -i`), it might not
   be desirable that `root` knows it.
   It depends on your password but if it is something like
   `ubuntu-Ak5"l,$7sH` then he might *guess* your Amazon or online banking
   password.

Having said that, I suggest what already was suggested: 
an entry for `sudo` – but slighly different:

I suggest putting a file in the directory `/etc/sudoers.d/` instead
of directly manipulating the file `/etc/sudoers`. The last line 
in `/etc/sudoers` reads

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Although this looks like a comment because of the leading `#`, *it is not*.
That's an exception to the usual comments. This directive means that all 
files below `/etc/sudoers.d` will also be considered when `sudo` does 
its work. See `/etc/sudoers.d/README` for further details.

**To be totally bulletproof, you need two terminal windows:** One as user 
`root` and one as user `fixit` (I simply assume that is your username). 
Open two terminal windows. In the **first window** type

```
sudo -i
```

and enter your password. Now you have a root shell to edit the sudoers 
stuff and to rollback in case something goes wrong.

In the **first window** type

```
cd /etc/sudoers.d
visudo -f fixit
```

This will open an editor (often `nano`) with the file `fixit`. 
The name doesn't matter as long as it doesn't contain a dot 
(so *don't* use e.g. `fixit.sudo`). Add the line

```
fixit ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/thunar
```

to that file and save it. The advantage of using `visudo` 
instead of a *regular* editor is that `visudo` will check 
the file for syntax and refuse to save a malformed file. 
Also, it will set the file's permissions properly. 
**Keep this first window open!**

Now go to your **second window** and try (as user `fixit`)

```
sudo thunar
```

It should work without asking for a password. If not, switch 
back to the first window (which you kept open with a root shell 
for exactly this purpose) and either fix the file 
`/etc/sudoers.d/fixit` or simply delete the file and start afresh.

If you want to add more commands to `/etc/sudoers.d/fixit`, 
simply add more lines (or a comma-separated list of commands):

```
fixit ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/thunar
fixit ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/othercommand
fixit ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/3rd_command, /usr/bin/4th_command, \
                      /usr/bin/5th_command_in_another_line
```

This approach has some advantages in my opinion:

- You don't even need to touch the *factory settings* 
  in `/etc/sudoers` (so no problems when an OS update occurs).
- You can carry your `/etc/sudoers.d/fixit` file to different
  computers by simply copying it there.
- You can easily undo your changes by deleting the file. 
  Or rename it so that it contains a dot because files 
  with dots in their filename are ignored by the `include`
  mechanism, for instance to `fixit.bak` or `fixit.disabled`.

Comment: Yes, sure. I appreciate that, @fixit7

Comment: It worked well. I made an alias. alias th='sudo thunar' @PerlDuck